# dynamic subdomains using .htaccess in php

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

i am trying to implement dynamic

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /live/agent/index.php?agent_user_name=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /live/agent/$1.php?agent_user_name=%1 [L]
```

Now this .htaccess converts

http://mydomain.com/live/agent/index.php?agent_user_name=username to http://username.mydomain.com

and

http://mydomain.com/live/agent/forum.php?agent_user_name=username to http://username.mydomain.com/form/

However, there are other pages as well which i want to redirect to subdomain like

http://mydomain.com/live/agent/view_blog.php?agent_user_name=username&blog_id=19 this page should be read via subdomain something like http://username.mydomain.com/view_blog/19 etc and also

http://mydomain.com/live/agent/page.php?agent_user_name=username&content_id=19 this page should be accessed by http://username.mydomain.com/content/19 etc

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^content/([0-9]+)/?$ /live/agent/page.php?agent_user_name=%1&blog_id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /live/agent/$1.php?agent_user_name=%1&blog_id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /live/agent/index.php?agent_user_name=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /live/agent/$1.php?agent_user_name=%1 [L]
```

Comment: anubhava, you didn't mention page_id variable in .htaccess rule... ??? there can be more extra variables as well like for blog section we may have blog.php?agent_user_name=username&page=1&search=property ????

Comment: There was no `page_id` in your examples. For more variables you can follow same pattern as I suggested and expand rules for extra variables.

Comment: RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /live/agent/$1.php?agent_user_name=%1&blog_id=$2 [L,QSA] for this rule, can u please advise if i change blog_id with page_id, how can i make it to access page.php instead of view_blog.php ???

Answer (score 0):

Add the following below your current rules should achieve what you want.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /live/agent/view_blog.php\?agent_user_name=(.*)&blog_id=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ http://%2.mydomain.com/view_blog/%3? [R,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /live/agent/page.php\?agent_user_name=(.*)&content_id=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ http://%2.mydomain.com/content/%3? [R,L]
```